# How to add a prop to a specific element by cloning the element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a prop to a specific React component, not to all of the component's children.

The function that add the prop looks like the following code:

```
addProps (children) {
const childProps = { doSomething: this.doSomething };

const recursiveAddProps = (children) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (child.type !== GrandChild){
      if (child.props) recursiveAddProps(child.props.children);
      return child;
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
  });
}
return recursiveAddProps(children);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/baL2bv0n/14/)

But that is not adding the function doSomething to the GrandChild component, so no onClick event is fired when the component is clicked on.

What would you do? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not cloning the intermediate children and ignoring the return value of recursiveAddProps. cloneElement doesn't mutate so you need to do it like this (untested):

```
const recursiveAddProps = (children) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (child.type !== GrandChild) {
      if (child.props) return React.cloneElement(child, {
          children: recursiveAddProps(child.props.children),
      });
      return child;
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
  });
}
```